# Do any of you use lrzip on your servers?

Tags: linux, compression

I have been reading about this: https://github.com/epa/lrzip and it seems that lrzip gets more bang for your money. My initial tests however showed takes quite long using lrztar. Any one here have experience using this on live servers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the usefullness of lrzip increases with RAM. How much RAM do your servers have? How big is the size of the uncompressed file? Filetype?